# Is it wise to delete C: (containing Program Files) on an old hard drive, to create space to backup more files?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm asking just for Windows. My old laptop died, and I removed its hard drive ("HD"). Now I'm using this as a backup HD. I partitioned it into C and D, because C contains all the "Program Files" and Windows files.  I kept all personal files on drive D that I already copied and pasted to my new HD on my new laptop.

Assume that I already re-installed all Program Files on the old computer, in the new computer, so that I don't need the .exe's on C in the old HD. I'm thinking of deleting C, so that I can free up space to back up more files.

1. Is deleting C on the old HD smart? What do I lose by deleting C on the old HD?
2. If I install this old HD into a new computer, can the new computer immediately operate on this old HD? I'm guessing the answer is no? I heard that you can't just reuse C drives on a new computer – even if your old HD ran perfectly on your old computer – you must re-install Windows and all the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I install this old HD into a new computer, can the new computer
> immediately operate on this old HD? I'm guessing the answer is no? I
> heard that you can't just reuse C drives on a new computer – even if
> your old HD ran perfectly on your old computer – you must re-install
> Windows and all the software?

The old drive likely will not boot because of BIOS and Drivers. That is the hardware reason.

It is very likely the old system was OEM. That means you cannot legally (with Microsoft's meaning) move the system to a new computer.

> So then, is deleting C on the old HD smart? What do I lose by deleting
> C on the old HD?

There is no harm deleting the old programs.

I further suggest you copy data to your new computer as old drives die anyway, and some drives that are old and were in use tend to die more. You might find a year from now that you cannot retrieve that data.

However if you are sure the drive is good, deleting programs to make space is fine.

Comment: "I further suggest you copy data to your new computer as old drives die anyway, and some drives that are old and were in use tend to die more. You might find a year from now that you cannot retrieve that data." Thanks. I did this. Don't hesitate to edit this out.